# Rails update action injecting Null in one of my fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, controller, null

I have an app with calls in it.  Each call can be cancelled.  When a call is cancelled in the cancel action I render a cancel_form which gives the user a cancellation reason to pick from and leverages the update action to write the param.

It functions fine however whenever I use this it wipes out my transfer_date field.  The params show the proper cancel_reason_id being set, then it sets transfer_date to NULL.  I have nothing in the code which touches the transfer_date so I'm puzzled.

Here's the code and output of params:

```
Params:
Processing by CallsController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"SoiMjWjeMFXXeiA9N8nNwfIQDa7pbB0YS9XkmKY6AuQ=", "call"=>{"cancel_reason_id"=>"1"}, "button"=>"", "id"=>"183"}
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 14 LIMIT 1
  Call Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "calls".* FROM "calls" WHERE "calls"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", "183"]]
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
   (0.6ms)  UPDATE "calls" SET "cancel_reason_id" = 1, "transfer_date" = NULL, "updated_at" = '2012-09-29 18:02:03.315975' WHERE "calls"."id" = 183
   (1.9ms)  COMMIT
```

CallsController Cancel action:

```
def cancel
        @call = Call.find(params[:id])

        attrs = {
          call_status: 'cancel', 
          incharge_id: @call.units.first.incharge_id, 
          attendant_id: @call.units.first.attendant_id
        }
        attrs.merge!({ incharge2_id: @call.units.second.incharge_id, attendant2_id: @call.units.second.attendant_id }) if @call.units.count == 2

        if @call.update_attributes(attrs)
          @call.units.each do |unit|
            CallMailer.cancel_call(unit.incharge, @call).deliver
            CallMailer.cancel_call(unit.attendant, @call).deliver
           end
         render "cancel_form"
        else 
          redirect_to calls_url, :error => "Whoops."
        end
      end
```

Cancel_form view

```
<%= form_for(@call) do |f| %>

  <%= f.label :cancel_reason %>
  <%= f.collection_select(:cancel_reason_id, CancelReason.all, :id, :reason, {}, {:class => 'select'}) %>

  <%= f.button :submit %>

<% end %>
```

I've tried creating a separate cancel_reason action and adding a route but it also leverages the update action apparently and sets transfer_date to NULL.

I really need this feature to work but I'm at the end of my troubleshooting skills for now.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have params[:call].parse_time_select! :transfer_date in my update action which parses my date/time into one field.  If I wrap this in a if transfer_date = nil statement I can create the call with the right date and keep a date in the cancel_reason view.  But it's skewed because I'm not parsing the date.  What would be the right if else or unless logic to use here?

Comment: I'm trying to run this only if the params key transfer_date exists.  This is what I have so far: if(params.has_key?(:transfer_date))
    params[:call].parse_time_select! :transfer_date
  end but it still doesn't parse the time.  Is my logic wrong?

Answer (score 0):

May be you just miss transfer_date in attr_accessible in Call model?

Comment: Nope, :transfer_date is in attr_accessible in the Call model.

Comment: I forgot to mention in my update action this line is set: params[:call].parse_time_select! :transfer_date  since the update being done on cancel_reason doesn't have any params to read on the transfer_date I think it's setting NULL.  Now how to get around it?

Answer (score 0):

```
 if params[:call].has_key? 'transfer_date(1i)'
      params[:call].parse_time_select! :transfer_date
    end
```

By including this conditional statement I was able to run the parse_time line for only requests that contain the params key transfer_date(1i).  This ended up solving my problem.